# Dynamically add Rows and Columns in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, google-api, visualization

I am working on google charts and want to add Rows and Columns Dynamically in Google Chart. I tried using below ajax but its not working.

Here `NumCols` comes undefined and getting an error while adding rows

> Uncaught Error: If argument is given to addRow, it must be an array, or null

Ajax:-

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '/home/DrawChart',     
        data: '{}',
        success: function (chartsdataSet) {             
            data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            var chartsdata = JSON.parse(chartsdataSet).Table;

            var numRows = chartsdata.length;
            var numCols = chartsdata[0].length;

            data.addColumn('string', chartsdata[0][0]);

            // all other columns are of type 'number'.
            for (var i = 1; i < numCols; i++)
                data.addColumn('number', chartsdata[0][i]);

            // now add the rows.
            for (var j = 1; j < numRows; j++)
                data.addRow(chartsdata[j]);
        chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('Graph1')); 
        chart.draw(data, options);   
    });
```

**JSON object after parsing:-**

[image: JSON object after parsing]

Answer (score 0):

Using below loops I get dynamic row and columns.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '/home/DrawChart',     
        data: '{}',
        success: function (chartsdataSet) {             
            data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            var chartsdata1 = JSON.parse(chartsdataSet).Table;
            var myVal = [];
            var colName;
            var colCount = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < chartsdata1.length; i++) {
                var row = chartsdata1[i];
                myVal.length = 0;
                $.each(row, function (key, value) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        if (colCount == 0) {
                            colName = key;
                            data1.addColumn('string', colName);
                            colCount += 1;
                        }
                        else {
                            data1.addColumn('number', key);
                        }
                    }
                    myVal.push(value);
                }); data1.addRow(myVal);
            }
});
```